# Подключить в микросервисном приложении один модуль в другой в Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, gradle

пытаюсь написать микросервисное приложение в котором несколько модулей. Один из модулей planner-entity необходимо подключить в другой модуль в этом же проекте.

Пытаюсь это сделать так: `implementation 'ru.test.micro.planner:planner-entity'` или так `implementation 'ru.test.micro.planner:planner-entity:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'` но выдает ошибку:

> planner-todo:main: Could not find
> ru.test.micro.planner:planner-entity:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Required by:
> project :

т.е. не может найти его почему-то. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему? Пробовал удалять папки `.gradle` и `build` заново собирал проект не помогло. Название и путь указаны верно.

build.gradle из модуля planner-entity:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'ru.test.micro.planner'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

build.gradle из модуля planner-todo:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'ru.test.micro.planner'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'ru.test.micro.planner:planner-entity:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
implementation project (':planner-entity')
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'planner-microservices'
include 'planner-entity'
```

С новой строки через `include` перечислите все модули в проекте

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Build file 'U:\Projects\Java\planner-microservices\planner-todo\build.gradle' line: 27

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'planner-todo'.
> Project with path ':planner-entity' could not be found in root project 'planner-todo'.

Comment: @Kolhoznik в settings.gradle модули подключены?

Comment: @Kolhoznik уберите settings.gradle в модулях и оставьте один в корне проекта

Comment: @Kolhoznik обновил ответ для вас